# Issues with dual booting windows 10/Ubuntu [solved]

Tags: dual-boot, usb, live-usb

I am using a usb to dual booting Ubuntu from my windows 10 laptop, and it successfully works, but when I use the same usb on my windows 10 gaming rig to boot Ubuntu it black screens. Any help with this issue?

Comment: What video card/chip? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it And be sure to boot in same boot mode UEFI or BIOS as current install(s). You may just need nomodeset, but some systems also need other boot parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change your boot mode in your bios settings for your "rig." Try changing the boot mode from legacy to UEFI or EFI (some also have a *both* mode which you can try) and let me know if that works. Furthermore there should be a bios key that will allow you to decide your boot order as well. Let me know if any of that was helpful.